# How to get multiple coordinates from 2d array in NumPy

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix `A`, and a (list of tuples) corresponding to coordinates `C`. How do I get `A[C]`?

For example:

```py
>>> A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> C
[(0,0), (1,2), (4,-1)]
```

The function I want, but don't know the name of, works like this:

```py
>>> func(A,C)
[0, 7, 24]
```

Does such a function (or some funky NumPy indexing syntax) exist, or is a `for` loop the only way to get this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a list of `X,Y` pairs. That can't be fed directly to an arrays indexer - it needs to be changed a bit.

Instead of `[(X,Y), (X,Y), (X,Y)]`, you need `[(X,X,X), (Y,Y,Y)]`:

```
>>> x = [x for x,y in C]
>>> y = [y for x,y in C]
>>> A[x, y]
array([ 0,  7, 24])
```

Or even simpler:

```
>>> A[tuple(zip(*C))]
array([ 0,  7, 24])
```

Comment: Awesome. The `A[tuple(zip(C))]` method (without the `*`) also works when C is another NumPy array (with a shape like `(2, x)`).